# Debugging a rehosted workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am using Dynamic activity and loading a workflow from xaml.
This xaml file is written using a rehosted WF designer.
Is there a way to debug this and go step by step through the activites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visual Workflow Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624139.aspx) WF4 sample app uses a rehosted WorkflowDesigner and steps through the activities. Not exactly what you are looking for but it should help you get started.

Comment: Actually it might do the job. Thanks a lot!